# rrule dates are offset by a week

Tags: python-dateutil, rrule

I'm getting an unexpected result using the `python-dateutil` `rrule` module and I'm wondering if this is WAI.

I'm dynamically creating the `rrule` using:

```
dtstart = datetime.date(2019, 1, 7)
until = datetime.date(2029, 11, 29)
freq = MONTHLY
byweekday=MO(2)
interval = 4
```

This results in the following rrule

```
DTSTART:20190107T000000
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=4;UNTIL=20291129T000000;BYDAY=+2MO
```

However, when generating the dates (looping on the rrule for this python module), I get the following dates:

```
 [datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 14, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 13, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 9, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 13, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 14, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 11, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 10, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 13, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 10, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 9, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 12, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 9, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 8, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 11, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 8, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 13, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2024, 9, 9, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2025, 1, 13, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2025, 5, 12, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2025, 9, 8, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2026, 1, 12, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2026, 5, 11, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2026, 9, 14, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2027, 1, 11, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2027, 5, 10, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2027, 9, 13, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2028, 1, 10, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2028, 5, 8, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2028, 9, 11, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2029, 1, 8, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2029, 5, 14, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2029, 9, 10, 0, 0)]
```

Notice that the first date is offset by a week! Why is this the case? And is this a bug in the library?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *not* a bug in the library. `2019-01-14` is the first date which matches your rule (it's the 2nd Monday of January 2019). Apparently python-dateutil has chosen to not include the start date you provide, which is completely legit.

`RRULE` is specified in [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545), which states in [Section 3.8.5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.3) (under "Description"):

> The recurrence set generated with a "DTSTART" property
> value not synchronized with the recurrence rule is undefined.

Which essentially means there is no right or wrong interpretation because the input data is "broken" if the start date doesn't match the rule.

Note, many other implementations would probably return both, your start date `2019-01-07` **and** the result `2019-01-14`. I don't think any implementation would omit `2019-01-14`, simply because it is the first date which matches the rule. It's debatable whether the start date `2019-01-07` should be in the results or not, but `2019-01-14` should definitely be in there.

Comment: Thanks. Just came back to this. Got it. What I was doing was asking for the second monday rather than the monday on the second week of the month. How would I go about modifying my query to ask for that?

Comment: Which second Monday? You mean Monday every other week? Like so `FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;BYDAY=MO`?

Answer (score 0):

In Python by_weekly code could be implemented like this.

```
from calendar import isleap

from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY, WEEKLY, MONTHLY 

def bi_weekly(start_date=datetime.now(),count=53,interval=2):
    """
      dateTImeSart = bi_weekly(datetime.strptime('2021-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d'),53)
      print(dateTImeSart[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
      print(dateTImeSart[1].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
      print(dateTImeSart[50].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
      print(dateTImeSart[51].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
      print(dateTImeSart[52].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
      2021-01-01
      2021-01-15
      2022-12-02
      2022-12-16
      2022-12-30
    """
    # returns the datetime for an year and calculates them for 1 By weekly
    return list(rrule(WEEKLY, count=count,interval=interval, dtstart=start_date))
```